# Permanently set thousend separator for PostgreSQL PSQL?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I use the following command to set thousand comma separator in PSQL every time i log in, but how do i set it permanently?

```
\pset numericlocale
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put that line in your `psqlrc` file which is located at `~/.psqlrc`.

Comment: I just created a new file .psqlrc in my ~/ and add the line, it works, thanks redneb!